# Retrieve the elements in a td and append to itself

Tags: jquery

I want to copy the elements in a td and append it to itself (the td) using jquery. With the following code, every time the button is clicked, all the element in the td will be copied. What should I do to make sure the only the original elements are copied every time the button is clicked?

```
$('.row-add').live("click", function () {
      var price = $(this).closest('td').html()
      $(this).closest("td").append(price);
    });
```

Here is the html

```
<td>
                $<input class="price" value="50"/>
                /
                <select>
                  <option>Second</option>
                  <option>Minute</option>
                  <option>Hour</option>
                  <option>Day</option>
                  <option>Week</option>
                  <option>Biweek</option>
                  <option selected="selected">Month</option>
                </select>
                /
                 <select>
                  <option>Day</option>
                  <option>Week</option>
                  <option>Biweek</option>
                  <option selected="selected">Month</option>
                  <option>Quarter</option>
                  <option>Year</option>
                </select>
                <span class="delete-td"></span>
                <span class="row-add"></span>
</td>
```

Comment: Please show your HTML, and also the HTML you want *after* it's been appended/manipulated. Also, you want to duplicate the *contents* of the `td` and duplicate those, or you want to duplicate the `td` *itself* (and append that (the `td`) inside the original `td`)?

Comment: you can't append an element to itself. that'd cause a loop in the DOM tree and break the universe. If you're trying to duplicate a row, why not clone the row?

Comment: I want to duplicate the contents of the td and append the contents duplicated to the same td. Is it possible?

Comment: @MarcB, the clone will duplicate the td tags as well. I don't want to put another td in the existing td.

Answer (score 0):

That function is working great for me.  I am using a simple table as html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="row-add">Click Me</td>
        <td>Not Me</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have copied your function verbatim.  Just make sure that the code is being run after the DOM has loaded and you should be fine.

Comment: If you have multiple elements in the td, it won't work ideally.

Answer (score 0):

There won't be a method to separate the initial contents from any appended data unless you wrap them (assuming you are appending into the cloned td). I'd suggest putting a span with a class around the original data and using a multi-part selector to only copy the original eg:

`var price = $(this).closest('td span .original').html()`